# XSL:FO - Page break on two dynamic areas?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I'm using XSLFast and was wondering if the following is possible:

I have a page with static content and one area containing a table that outputs XML-data. The table is set to a specific height so that the page breaks when the height is reached and continues outputting one the next page.
Now,
I want to add another area containing such a table with the exact feature. Is that possible on one side?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  Do you mean two tables side-by-side?  Also, what is on the next page?  More of the same logical table or what?

Comment: OK, I'm sorry, I'm trying to clarify:

Answer (score 0):

I have never used XSLFast, but...

XSL 1.1 allows an `fo:simple-page-master` to have multiple `fo:region-body`. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_simple-page-master.)  I do not know if XSLFast supports it, but with a formatter that supports multiple `fo:region-body`, you could put the red table and the blue table in separate `fo:flow` and direct them to the two different `fo:region-body`.  The formatter would then make another page whenever either `fo:region-body` overflowed.